# How to phrase to business why refactoring is important

Tags: java, spring, architecture, exception, entities

I am currently working on a project with some (in my opinion) architectural problems.

For example - every dependency is retrieved when needed from a common Framework Bean that every object has access to via a static method. This is in effect just a wrapper around spring that will return a Spring bean. No dependency injection.

Entities have references to DAO's to retrieve relational data - hidden in the Entity getters.

Exceptions have references to services to parse and translate error messages.

Every service or DAO inherits from some common abstract framework bean that have their own dependencies and configuration requirements. If you try to do anything else you will get a 'Framework not initialized' error. It should also be mentioned that the Framework is a black box that noone dares touch.

Every test is in effect an integrationn test as all of them requires a working database connection to a central, shared database.

We have a dependency graph that everything is connected to everything, basically.

And no tests.

Imagine how hard it is to set up a unit test in this environment. In fact every test tries to insert test data and clean up after itself - without using any kind of transaction.

And I'm only scratching the surface here.

Needless to say, I worry a little about the code quality. The project is (of course) running low on time and resources, and deadline is approaching.

So - How to convince management in a language they understand that refactoring is needed if we shall have any hope of delivering something that resembles functional software?

Comment: Good luck, I've been trying to convince management to let me refactor for 6 months now

Comment: Cost of Implementation vs Return on Investment

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's the return of investment case I find it hard to argue for. In the end the result will be a disaster and unhappy customers, what's the cost of that? I guess the inverse of this cost would be the return on investment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem.

Comment: Question might fit on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best approach is:

1. Metrics: Collect all the possible data about the problems caused by the use of the current architecture. Analyze the information and separate it in topics of interest like: reliability, efficiency, security and Maintainability. (See: [Software quality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality#Measurement))
2. Visual: Make beautiful bar charts and pie charts with the analyzed info.
3. Diff: Compare your results with an standard or ideal metrics.

With this you are ready to present your point of view of the project to the management.

Usually this work is responsibility of project manager, team manager, or team leader.

Good luck!

Comment: I think this is a great answer. I saw a presentation once were someone used comparisons with opensource codebased to show the problems. If you need a metaphor I always talk about cooks in a kitchen, and how it needs cleaning as you go.. If you don't clean as you go soon all the surfaces are cluttered, the floor is slippy and people make mistakes.. and the speed new meals can be created slows.  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in many cases refactoring may not be good for business, because benefits are less than cost.  In other cases benefits may be bigger than cost, but cost is too much to be payed right now.  Try to estimate benefits and cost of refactoring in some units which business can convert to $$$, i.e. in man hours of developers, testers and support team, in hours of system unavailability, etc and let business decide whether refactoring is worth to be done, or not.  Such decisions is where business is stronger than developers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project that is similar in dependencies. Unit testing it isn't ideal. I'm mocking so many classes in each my tests that simply running the full application in a development environment is a better solution.

I guess it depends on your application. Mine was a custom web application serving HTTP requests. I turned it on and sent all sorts of requests to try and follow all possible paths. It is more of a functional test than unit testing, but I found the process to be much faster and my log statements were informative enough to lead me to bugs in specific class or methods.

I wrote my code, functional tested it in dev. environment, then when I found time, I slowly added unit tests to classes.

Talk to them about the expected changes that might affect the future of your application, new features, requirements, technologies, etc. The project might not warrant refactoring if it'll never evolve.

**I am not saying functional testing is a replacement for unit testing.**

Answer (score 0):

If you think you need to persuade "the business" about the benefits of refactoring, what you have in mind is **not** refactoring. Refactoring is a kind of redesign, but not all redesign is refactoring. A refactoring is a small, incremental design improvement. As it is small, it is cheap and quick. So it does not need approval from "the business": you can *just do it*. It sounds like what you really have here is that the existing code is *not fit for purpose*. So you should be trying to petsuafe them of that, rather than trying to persuade them of the need to do something that will sound to them like needless "polishing".